# How to find which app interrupted audio session in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am developing an Audio player app.

I am using AVAudioSession for handling AVPlayer playback session and interruptions. I am getting interruption notification and able to pause/play audio based on that.

All I want to fetch is reason why audio has been interrupted for Analytics purpose.

Here's my code using which I am configuring AVAudioSession and handling Audio interruptions.

> 1. AVAudioSession Configuration

```
// AudioSession Configuration
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: .allowAirPlay)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed: \(error)")
}
try? audioSession.setActive(true)
```

> 2. AVAudioSession Interruption notification add observer :

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
```

> 3. AVAudioSession Interruption handle notification :

```
@objc private func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
            let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
                return
        }
        
        switch type {
        case .began:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.pause(pauseReason: .interruption)
                print("handleInterruption :- Pause")
            }
        case .ended:
            guard let optionsValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else { return }
            let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
            if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                // Interruption ended. Playback should resume.
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.play(isResume: true)
                    print("handleInterruption :- Play")
                }
            }
            else {
                // Interruption ended. Playback should not resume.
                self.pause(pauseReason: .interruption)
                print("handleInterruption :- Pause")
            }
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Is there any **function/delegate/notification** using which I can find the reason why audio playback has been interrupted ?

I want to get the Audio Playback Interruption Reasons like

1. Other Music Apps ( like Gaana, Wynk )
2. Call/SMS etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, iOS won't allow this due to privacy